# Progress bar with redundant slides

Tags: beamer

I have some redundant slides and i want that my progress bar doesnt evolve during these particular slides. For the page numbering there is no problem as i used "[noframenumbering]". In my example, the third frame is redundant of the second 'blabla2'. I can block the numbering with [noframenumbering] but the progress bar continues...i want to stop it after the second frame.

```
\documentclass[compress,8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{specifictheme}
\title{Test}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    blabla1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    blabla2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    blabla2
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok sorry is it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an easy workaround: just don't use separate frames:

```
\documentclass[compress,8pt]{beamer}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    blabla1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{onlyenv}<1>
        blabla2
    \end{onlyenv}
    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        blabla3
    \end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didnt know we can do that. I will test that thanks for your help ;)